# cannot change scope property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

im trying to change an property value into the $scope variable of angular js, but the applied changes has not been setted.

my code is this:

in my code i have an costBudget with many childs into an array, and i need to reeplace these child for the costWorkPackages array.

```
let costBudget = $scope.list[0];
costBudget.subCostsWorkPackages = costsWorkPackages;
console.log(costBudget);
```

the costBudget variable is the same before and after to assign the new array, and its wrong. I expect the costBudget has the new childs, but does not happens.

UPDATED:
added console objects:

before the change:

```
{code: 1, internalId: 0, notRealWorkPackage: true, name: "shrh", 
count: 1, …}
$$hashKey: "object:190"
code: 1
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(3)
0: Resource {id: 6491, name: "ascasca", count: 1,         
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(0), resourceInstances: Array(0), …}
1: Resource {id: 6492, name: "ascasca", count: 1, 
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(0), resourceInstances: Array(0), …}
2: Resource {id: 6493, name: "ascasca", count: 1, 
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(0), resourceInstances: Array(0), …}
$promise: Promise {$$state: {…}}
$resolved: true
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
 subNodeClass: ""
title: "shrh"
toggleButtonClass: "fa-minus-square-o"
__proto__: Object
```

after:

```
{code: 1, internalId: 0, notRealWorkPackage: true, name: "shrh", 
count: 1, …}
$$hashKey: "object:190"
code: 1
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(3)
0: Resource {id: 6491, name: "ascasca", count: 1, subCostsWorkPackages: Array(0), resourceInstances: Array(0), …}
1: Resource {id: 6492, name: "ascasca", count: 1, subCostsWorkPackages: Array(0), resourceInstances: Array(0), …}
2: Resource {id: 6493, name: "ascasca", count: 1, subCostsWorkPackages: Array(0), resourceInstances: Array(0), …}
$promise: Promise {$$state: {…}}
$resolved: true
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
subNodeClass: ""
title: "shrh"
toggleButtonClass: "fa-minus-square-o"
__proto__: Object
```

UPDATE 2:

costsWorkPackage variable in console:

```
[Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, $promise: Promise, $resolved: 
true]
0: Resource {id: 6430, name: "Nombre 2", count: "1.00000000", 
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(0), resourceInstances: Array(0), …}
1: Resource {id: 6437, name: "Nombre 9", count: "1.00000000", 
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(0), resourceInstances: Array(0), …}
2: Resource {id: 6438, name: "Nombre 3", count: "1.00000000", 
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(5), resourceInstances: Array(2), …}
3: Resource {id: 6431, name: "Nombre 3", count: "1.00000000", 
subCostsWorkPackages: Array(5), resourceInstances: Array(2), …}
$promise: Promise {$$state: {…}}
$resolved: true
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Please do a `console.log(costBudget);` right after `let costBudget = $scope.list[0];` and show us the results of both console logs.

Comment: i added the result logs, before and after.

Comment: Can you please show what is inside `costsWorkPackages` as well?

Comment: sure, i edited again.

Comment: well I see no logical error, try `let costBudget = angular.copy($scope.list[0]);` and if you're certain that `subCostsWorkPackages` property is to be replaced by `costsWorkPackages` everytime, then right after `let costBudget = angular.copy($scope.list[0]);` add this: `costBudget.subCostsWorkPackages = [];` and then replace it. Check if anything changes.

Comment: nothing is happening when assigning the empty array. It is still the same object. I used angular.copy before to re assign the variable.